# Can we switch to another window without using switchTo() method through Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to switch window without using switchTo() method in Selenium webdriver ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please read how to post a question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , then edit your question with some example of your code. :)

Comment: Why do you want another thing with same result ? Develop more your question. Explain why you don't want to use `switchTo()` method

Comment: If you want to control the window `switchTo()` is the only way.

Comment: It is not that I  don't want to use switchTo() method. I was at this interview and interviewer argued with me that there is a way to switch window without using the switchTo() method. So just thought of clarifying this out. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Answering straight **No**, you won't be able to switch window without using **`switchTo()`** method through *Selenium Webdriver*.

All the WebDriver commands happen in the context of either the [**current browsing context**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-current-browsing-context) or the [**current top-level browsing context**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-current-top-level-browsing-context). The *current top-level browsing context* is represented in the protocol by its associated window handle. When a [**top-level browsing context**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#top-level-browsing-context) is selected using the [**`Switch To Window`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-window) command, a specific browsing context can be selected using the [**`Switch to Frame`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-frame) command.

> **Note**: The use of the term **`window`** to refer to a [top-level browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#top-level-browsing-context) is legacy and doesn’t correspond with either the operating system notion of a “window” or the DOM [**`Window`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-window) object.

### Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle)

- HTTP Method

  ```
  POST
  ```
- URI Template

  ```
  /session/{session id}/window
  ```
- Command

  ```
  Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle)
  ```

> **Note**: Switching window will select the *current top-level browsing context* used as the target for all subsequent commands. In a tabbed browser, this will typically make the tab containing the browsing context the selected tab.